# Unbind change event

Tags: jquery

I'm triggering the Change event on change of dropdown, I have to remove `selected` attr on change, following is the code...

cshtml

```
      <select id="ddlKeywords" name="KeywordsCollection" onchange="Images.ClearFieldsOnKeywordSelect()" multiple>
        <option value="">Please select keywords</option>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.keywords)
        {
        <option value="@item.Code">@item.Description</option>
        }
      </select>
```

Jquery

```
  me.ClearFieldsOnKeywordSelect = function () {        
        $('#ddlKeywords option[value=]').removeAttr('selected').change();
        .........................
```

as you can see `.change()` event gets triggered while removing attr.

I have tried `unbind('change').change()`, `off('change').change()`, `unbind().change()`, `off().change()` but none of them has worked.

And `unbind('change')` does not remove the `selected` attr

Comment: Please include your html

Comment: @sumeshTG I have updated the question

Comment: and why you want to remove attribute? and add change code?

Comment: The change event is common for drop down. Do you want to remove `select` change event?

Comment: @Justcode it's a multiple select, and I have to remove the default selected on select of other options

Comment: `$("#ddlKeywords ").attr('selectedIndex', '-1').find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");` use index to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is just `$('#ddlKeywords option[value=]').attr('selected', false)`, which will remove the attribute without triggering the change event.

Also, you should provide a value for the option(s) that you want to remove the attribute from, or not add the specifier at all.

And for further reference, the `unbind` method requires a function to unbind (it uses the `removeEventListener` function under the hood.

Comment: No, this does not remove the attr